# React-Native: Text is rendering differently in different mobile phones

Tags: react-native, density-independent-pixel, ppi

This is the style I ma using to render Text

```
 TEXT_B16: {
    fontFamily: 'OpenSans-Bold',
    fontWeight: fontWeight,
    fontSize: 16,
    lineHeight: 22,
},
```

And output is as follows,

Samsung

[image]

One plus

[image]

iPhone 12 Pro Max

[image]

iPhone 6

[image]

even though Styling is same, fontSize and fontWeight are different in different screens.

Is it the natural thing that happens in mobile apps or is there any way to bring some uniformity across multiple devices?

(Please excuse for bigger images. If I compress then it would be difficult to identify differences)

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

In your text component disable `allowFontScaling`

```
<Text allowFontScaling={false} />
```

Comment: Still the result is same. Any alternatives?